# How to sign up to Geoserver with Spring Boot and display the styles/layers

Tags: spring-boot, geoserver

I have a problem with signing in to geoserver by WebClient(It has to be WebClient) and displaying the styles or displays on the localhost:8090
The geoserver is on docker and his link is http://10.56.56.66:8081/geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.GeoServerLoginPage?1
and after i sing in a I have to display for example styles from link
http://10.56.56.66:8081/geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.wms.web.data.StylePage?3&filter=false

Here is my code.

GeoServerConnectionProperty.java

```
package exp;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;


@Component
@RestController
public class GeoserverConnectionProperty {

    WebClient webClient = WebClient.create();

    @GetMapping("/GetLayers")
    public String getLayers()
    {
        return webClient.get()
                .uri("http://10.56.56.66:8081/geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.data.layer.LayerPage?9&filter=false")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .block();
    }

    @GetMapping("/GetStyles")
    public String getStyles()
    {
        return webClient.get()
                .uri("http://10.56.56.66:8081/geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.wms.web.data.StylePage")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .block();
    }

    @GetMapping("/status")
    public String login()  {
        String loginUrl = "http://10.56.56.66:8081/geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.GeoServerLoginPage?1";
        String username = "geoserver";
        String password = "geoserver";

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(loginUrl, String.class);

        webClient.post()
                .uri(loginUrl)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData("username", username)
                        .with("password", password))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .subscribe(responseBody -> {
                    System.out.println("Zalogowano: " + responseBody);
                }, error -> {
                    System.out.println("Błąd: " + error.getMessage());
                });

        return response.getBody();
    }
}
```

I tried a lot of think like deleting the cookies or things like this. Please help me login to geoserver and display the layers or styles on http://localhost:8090/status.

Comment: I changed login method and error 302 appears

webClient.get().uri(login)
 .retrieve()
 .bodyToMono(String.class)
  .flatMap(loginPage -> webClient.post().uri(login)
 .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData("username", user)
 .with("password", pass))
.exchange()
.flatMap(response -> {
if (response.statusCode().is3xxRedirection()) {
String redirectedUrl = response.headers().header("Location").get(0);
return webClient.get().uri(redirectedUrl)
.retrieve()
 .bodyToMono(String.class);
} else {
  return Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Error " + response.statusCode().value()));
}
 }));

Comment: Why not use the Rest API which is designed for this?

Comment: What do You mean exaclty with Rest API? I thought that this is Rest API

Comment: the rest API is at `http://10.56.56.66:8081/geoserver/rest/`

Comment: I went on this link and I have text like "Index -1 out of bounds for length 0"

Please, I am completely new to this. Can You please tell me step by step what should I do? It is really important to me. I am in my first job and it is my first task and I am fighting with this for over a weekend. 
I would really appreciate this !

Comment: I'd start by reading the manual - https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/rest/index.html#rest

Comment: I have read this thank You. Changed the link, but right now I have problem 401 Unauthorized from GET.


"401 Unauthorized from POST http://10.56.56.66:8081/geoserver/rest"

Comment: You will need to log in as admin

Comment: I did it man. Thank You so much from the bottom of my hearth. God bless You. Have a nice day

Comment: @IanTurton please, can You help me one more time? I have to make possible to edit and add style into geoserver by Rest Api.  Please let me know.

Comment: @IanTurton please are You there?

Comment: https://geoserver.org/support/

Comment: I will buy You a coffe If You`re gonna help me, cause I literally do not understand it well. I am trying.